# if..else statement not working in foreach loop

Tags: asp.net

Else statement not working properly in foreach loop? Here's my code. If something's wrong with my code explanations would be nice.

```
protected void getdata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db2 = new cftzClassDataContext())
    {
        var username = (from p in db2.cftzAccounts
                        where p.username.Equals(getdata2.Text)
                        select p);
        foreach (var p in username)
        {
            if (getdata2.Text == p.username)
            {
                displayMSG.Text = "Is this correct ";
                displayData.Text = p.username;
                displayQuestionMark.Text = "?";
            }
            else
            {
                displayMSG.Text = "No User Found.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that you are always overwriting that "displayMSG.Text"? The last one will win!

Comment: else is not working :( i dont know why

Comment: @HansKesting That's ok because every element in the list has the same username ;)

Comment: In that case it will never hit the Else surely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `if` statement is entirely redundant, as you have already filtered your list to only include accounts where the username equals `getData2.Text`. Therefore, your `if` test will always evaluate to `true`.

You can rewrite it as this, with the same effect

```
    using (var db2 = new cftzClassDataContext())
    {
        var username = (from p in db2.cftzAccounts.Take(100)
                        where p.username.Equals(getdata2.Text)
                        select p);

        foreach (var p in username)
        {
            displayMSG.Text = "Is this correct ";
            displayData.Text = p.username;
            displayQuestionMark.Text = "?";
        }
    }
```

However, as Hans points out, your loop is unnecessary as well, as all the usernames will be the same. Your code could be as simple as:

```
    using (var db2 = new cftzClassDataContext())
    {
        var user = db2.cftzAccounts.
              FirstOrDefault(account => account.username.Equals(getdata2.Text));

        if (user != null)
        {
            displayMSG.Text = "Is this correct ";
            displayData.Text = user.username;
            displayQuestionMark.Text = "?";
        }
        else 
        {
            displayMSG.Text = "No User Found.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah - I think I understand your problem now. You want to get the account belonging to the username. If no account exists, you want to display an appropriate message. Please see the 2nd piece of code that I just added.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you try to achieve, but it looks like you are try to find if user is in database and if so, configure displayMSG object.
 cant you do something like

```
var user=db2.Single(u=> u.username==getdata2.Text);
```

if no user is found, Singe will throw an exception. If you dont wont that, you can use SingleOrDefault() method

```
protected void getdata_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var db2 = new cftzClassDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var user=db2.Single(u=> u.username==getdata2.Text);
            displayMSG.Text = "Is this correct ";
            displayData.Text = user.username;
            displayQuestionMark.Text = "?";
        }
        catch
        {
            displayMSG.Text = "No User Found.";
        }
    }
}
```